# Downgrade OBIEE 12c Repository to 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, obiee, downgrade

Is it possible to downgrade a 12c repository to OBIEE 11g on windows server?

I tried "nqgenoldverrpd.exe" way but I got error below

"Reading D:\TEMP\BI_Model\XX_Repository.rpd...
The following repository cannot be opened: D:\TEMP\BI_Model\XX_Repository.rpd"

Does anyone have any idea, please help me :)

Comment: Which "12c" to which "11g"? What "nqgenoldverrpd.exe" are you using to attack which RPD file? The one from "12c" or "11g"?

And most importantly: WHY?! That's the worst step you can make. You're voluntarily going to a non-supported version that's outdated.

Comment: Hi Chris, I try to convert my repository from 12.2.1.4.0 (12c) to 11.1.1.9.160119 (11g). I know that is the worst way but one of my customers doesn't have licence for 12c and I use 12c on my machine and I developed my repository on 12c. So I have to find a way for convertion. If I don't have a way so I will develop all my changes on 11g again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nqgenoldverrpd only work within one product family. So inside the 11g product family or inside the 12c product family.

It does not support jumps from 11g to 12c.

Moving changes "down" one full release is a tricky thing and can lead to problems.

Comment: Thank you for your attention Chris.